Geometry Nodes: Apply Fillet to part of a Curve
Is there a way to apply fillet curves to parts of a curve, perhaps by separating it into parts and recombining after the fillet? In my case I would target corners based on an angle threshold.

Hello madscribbles, first you calculate the curve angle (Thanks to Markus von Broady) then you establish the angle threshold and with a multiply you choose the filet radius:


The blend:

I hope it Helps.
